# jquery/ajax problem

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there anything wrong in my code? When I start the program, the proccess isn't doing anything. I want to retrieve information with jQuery's `ajax` function, from two functions from my controller, I use the Codeigniter framework. I access the functions by **url: $(".SelectSubCategory").load("location/func2")**. But like I said, nothing is happening.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(".SelectCategory").change( function() {
        var category=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'category='+ category;
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(".SelectSubCategory").load("location/func2"),
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".SelectSubCategory").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
    $(".SelectSubCategory").change( function() {
        var category=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'category='+ category;
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(".SelectFunction").load("location/func"),
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".SelectFunction").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you add: `error: function(e){ alert('Error: ' + e); }` to your call?

Comment: Are you sure that $(".SelectSubCategory").load("location/func2") returns a valid url for your post?

Comment: no, no errors, urls are fine, everythings is set but no output, the db and controller is ok two, so i think its from here the ajax.

Comment: What do you mean by urls are fine? Based on the code you have posted, the URL's are being assigned jQuery objects which are absolutely not fine, unless you have tweaked the code before you posted it.

Comment: I fixed it it was the change event, he was making the problem.Still thanx

Answer (score 1):

Why are you assigning jQuery objects to the URL option of ajax calls 
i.e

```
url: $(".SelectSubCategory").load("location/func2")
url: $(".SelectFunction").load("location/func")
```

url option should be a valid URL of the same domain from where the page is loaded.

Something like: `url:"location/func2"`
or `url:"do/something/file.php"`
etc.

Comment: Agreed. I think that needs to be a valid string. You can set a variable to equal whatever is returned from your function, then use that variable as the URL.

Question: I'm wondering if you can set that function as a variable. Would it work then? For instance:

var functionName = function(someVar){ /somecodeheretoreturncandy}

Comment: I fixed it it was the change event, he was making the problem.Still thanx

Answer (score 0):

You need to retieve the url first and then make your ajax call. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"location/func2",
    success: function(html) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: val,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".SelectSubCategory").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried the output just the url from the first request?

Comment: I fixed it it was the change event, he was making the problem.Still thanx